# why one omp thread completes while other unable to do same?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

i am trying to execute following code and expecting 1st for loop to be divided amongst 2 threads which works fine,

the 2nd for loop was to be executed in "entirety" 2 times i.e.  by thread 0 as well as thread 1 which is not happening as the output shows.

```
omp_set_num_threads(2);
#pragma omp parallel
{

#pragma omp for
for(i=65;i<91;i++)
printf("%c ",i);

printf("\n\n");

//if(omp_get_thread_num()==1) //if enalbled then prints all a->z letters
{

for(i=97;i<123;i++){
printf("%c %d",i,omp_get_thread_num());
#pragma omp flush
}

}
#pragma omp barrier
}
```

## Run 1

A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 1g 1h 1i 1j 1k 1l 1m 1n 1o 1p 1q 1r 1s 1t 1u 1v 1w 1x 1y 1z 1

a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 0g 0h 0i 0j 0k 0l 0m 0n 0o 0p 0q 0r 0s 0t 0u 0v 0w 0x 0y 0z 0

## Run 2

A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 0g 0

a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 1g 1h 1i 1j 1k 1l 1h 0n 0o 0p 0q 0r 0s 0t 0u 0v 0w 0x 0y 0z 0m 1

so what might be the reason that thread 1 is not printing all a-z?
switching may occur but ,as the "implicit" barrier exists at the end of parallel construct 
 so thread 1 -thread0 must have waited for each other to finish.

i tried 8-9 runs and noticed that thread 1 always unable to print its expected output!

> on enabling the if condition thread1 successfully prints a-z on every run (checked 12 times!!)

Comment: Because you have a race condition in `i`.  Make it private.

Answer (score 0):

this should work as you want:

omp_set_num_threads(2);

```
#pragma omp for
for(i=65;i<91;i++)
printf("%c ",i);

printf("\n\n");

#pragma omp parallel private(i)
{

for(i=97;i<123;i++)
printf("%c %d",i,omp_get_thread_num());
}
```